# Angular 2 json modify data

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to modify JSON. If the JSON has accNo then modify  the name value as name: name  accNo. If no accNo then leave name as it is

eg. For name : "abc", accNo : 123. Modify name as "abc 123"

```js
var data = [
  {
    name : "abc",
    accNo : 123
  },
  {
    name : "xyz"
  },
  {
    name : "mon",
    accNo : 345
  },
  {
    name : "spo",
    accNo : 789
  },
  {
    name : "cdo"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is not a valid json.

Comment: i was trying _.map(users, (i)=>{
    if(i.No){
        i.user = i.user+":"+i.No;
    }
});

Comment: it gave me value as undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#map` to create your array.

```js
var data = [ { name : "abc", accNo : 123 }, { name : "xyz" }, { name : "mon", accNo : 345 }, { name : "spo", accNo : 789 }, { name : "cdo" } ]

var result = data.map(({name, accNo}) => {
  if(accNo) {
    return ({name: name + " : " + accNo, accNo});
  } else {
    return {name};
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't modify your JSON, but I will modify the response of your http call. Hope you don't mind.

```
let formattedRes = httpRes.map(item => ({
  name: item.accNo ? `${item.name} ${item.accNo}` : item.name, 
  accNo: accNo
}));
```